# How could I better layout a list of 200+ members?

Tags: layout, lists, content

I'm looking for suggestions on how I can lay out this long list of members.
[image: long list of members]

Just for some extra context, when you select a person's name an overlay will appear with their information along with a picture of them.

I already have in mind how the overlay will look but I'm looking for alternatives to just listing out the names of each member (as shown in the image above).

The goal is to ultimately get users to want to join this group of members. The list serves as a way for the user to get to know the type of people that are already members. A lot of the members do share similar titles so separating them by that might be an option

Comment: With this many people to list I think listing them out might be the best solution but I'd love to hear any ideas you guys might have.

Comment: It would really help to know what is the user goal when this data is presented. Will users look for a specific person? How? By firstname? Secondname? Perhaps the list can be broken down to departments? Age? Attractiveness? So what is the list for and why users need it.

Comment: Great question, the goal is to ultimately get users to want to join this group of members. The list serves as a way for the user to get to know the type of people that are already members. A lot of the members do share similar titles so separating them by that might be an option...

Comment: not really an answer to the question, but anyone with lists this big must take care with their filtering and sorting UX :-)

Comment: best example is your facebook friendlist

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the goal is to get current members seen and to entice new members to join, you probably want to focus on the people themselves, not a list of names that require further, individual interaction.

One solution: [image: Cbusr.com - uses small cards and lazy loading to present members]

Cbusr.com - uses small cards and lazy loading to present members

Comment: I really like this solution but listing out that many people on a page might be an issue. I'm thinking of taking this concept and putting a limit on how many members load and allow the user to load more profiles if they want.

Comment: @Nekst That's why it uses lazy loading, as mentioned.

Comment: I would just like to further support this solution. There is substantial evidence showing user are more emotionally engaged when presented with faces.

Comment: Yeah, faces humanize the experience.